# Можно ли нажать 3 клавишу сразу в pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

и так, мне нужно нажать Ctrl + shift + n одновременно, но как я заю, в pyautogui можно нажать только 2 раза `pyautogui.hotkey('клавиша1', 'клавиша2')`

но как мне нажать 3 клавишы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'n')
```

В [документации](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-hotkey-function) как раз пример на 3 клавиши и приведён.